# Matlab imagesc plot

Tags: matlab

I have data which produces an image as shown in the first figure below.

[image]

How can I transform it to look like the one in figure two - transformed image?

[image]

**Please note**, first image and second image are two different data sets which are not related at all. What I have is data in image 1 and I want the result to look like the one in the second figure.

Comment: It seems not be only be matter of changing the "shape" of the image. The two graphs you've posted represent two different set of data. The first is Doppler m/s Vs Frames, the second is Doppler Hz Vs Time. What is the actual question? How to make the charts given the data or how to process the data to go from the first set to the second?

Comment: Hi il_raffa, I have edited to my question for better understanding.

Comment: Fundamentally, the two plots are visualizing two different shapes of data. The top plot is a line plot - the data is a pair of 1D vectors {e.g. y =f(x)}. The bottom plot is a pcolor, or surf plot of a 2D function {eg. z = f(x,y)}. Perhaps you can convolve a Gaussian distribution (e.g.) with the function in the top plot to make a 2D function  that appears similar to the bottom. If you just want a fat line, you can set that during plotting: plot(x,y,'LineWidth',12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may proceed something like this:

```
N = 100 ; 
x = linspace(0,2*pi,N)' ; 
y = sin(x) ; 

xi = linspace(min(x),max(x),N) ; 
yi = linspace(min(y)-1,max(y)+1,N) ; 
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xi,yi) ; 
Z = zeros(size(X)) ; 
idx = knnsearch([X(:) Y(:)],[x y]) ; 
Z(idx) = 1 ; 
Z(idx+1) = 1 ; 
Z(idx-1) = 1 ; 
pcolor(X,Y,Z)
shading interp
colorbar
colormap(jet)
```